# Does Lufthansa allow you to choose seats for free during checking-in online?

Tags: seating, check-in, lufthansa

When I booked my flight with Lufthansa, an early seat reservation was available for an extra fee. But I did not want to pay extra so I just skipped this step.

Is it possible for me to check-in online 24h before the departure ? Do I need to pay if I want to select my seat during online checking-in or is it free of charge?

I travelled with other airlines and it was possible to online check-in 24h before departure without additional fee.

Comment: I've never heard of any airline making you pay to check-in online, so I'm pretty certain you can check-in online for free 24h before

Comment: In my experience, the check-in for Lufthansa is allowed 23 hours before. So don't be surprised if it doesn't work 24 hours before.

Comment: Update from a booking on Jan25 2022 - Long haul flight from SFO to BLR involving Air Canada and Lufthansa with 2 kids (2 and 9 years).  Air Canada immediately reserved adjacent seats for free (owing to kids) as part of the booking itself. Nothing from Lufthansa so need to check for adjacent seats during check-in (23 hours before departure now)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seat selection information is available on Lufthansa's site [here](https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Seat-reservation).

> Free seat selection during check-in
>
> You may, of course, choose any of
>   the remaining seats free of charge as soon as check-in for the
>   respective flight begins – usually 23 hours before departure. Please
>   note that selection is limited under these conditions.

Payment information for economy seating is available [here](https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/seat-reservation-economy-class).

Free seat selection is also available based on status.

Comment: Great, so it is possible to select my seat during online checking-in (23 hours before departure) and it is free of charge. that was my question!

Comment: @yaya Yes. There is an asterisk there, but there's no explanation on the page for what it is though!

Comment: 90 Euros to select a seat?!

Comment: No, it was about 12 Euro if I want to select seat during booking!

Comment: The €90 seat is for extra leg room. So it is not just a seat selection.

Comment: This information is out of date now.

Comment: @Muffo Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, however it's when the online check in opens which is currently 23hrs before your flight schedule. This the only way (except having FTL status or higher) you can reserve a seat for FREE on Lufthansa flights. You can find it here in this link (http://www.lufthansa.com/uk/en/Help-and-Contact) by typing in Can I choose a seat when using online check-in?

Answer (score 0):

I booked a ticket through united on Lufthansa flight. I went to Lufthansa website and changed the seat. I got exit row seat on both the flights without any charges

Answer (score -3):

Lufthansa has changed this about early 2015, and *any* seat assignment now costs money.

If you are not willing to pay, you can wait until you are at the desk in the airport, and then they will assign you a seat for free - that could be an exit row seat, or a dreaded middle seat between two overweight smelly guys; but mostly the latter.

Often, you can book the same flight (for some $/€ less) through a code-share partner, and there you can pick your seat for free at the time of booking. As more and more people learn that, a) all good seats are often gone, and b) Lufthansa is considering adjusting this process (as they lose revenue). I might have missed the change back, as I don't book Lufthansa anymore (see above), but it might have happened already or it might not.

Comment: Really? I selected my own seats several times this year for free.

Comment: Then they changed it back already, maybe. Or you booked not the cheapest class, or you are a miles&more member with some status.

Comment: Well I'm not so good with the number of miles, so I don't think it's that. Maybe they did change something.

Comment: I've never seen a Lufthansa flight that didn't assign you a seat during online check-in.  I haven't been assigned a seat at a checkin desk in years, mainly because they barely exist anymore. And I fly on the cheap tickets.